# Fake webcam for adobe flash player

Tags: flash, webcam, device-driver

I would like to make a fake webcam or "software" webcam that would stream videos/music from a computer file. The flash player can stream a webcam but not video. The idea is to trick adobe flash into thinking it is streaming from a webcam, but instead stream a computer video file. This is for flash player only. What is the simplest way to do it. Does adobe flash uses directx interface to access the camera, and if so is it possible to avoid making a windows driver?

Comment: Why make your own when it already exists?  http://www.webcamxp.com   or http://very-soft.com/wcs

Comment: I need to insert it into a larger program. I either need an open source solution, or advice on how to do it.

Comment: The driver option is probably going to be the best, and most compatible.  Is the flash bit part of that larger program?  If so, can you somehow forge the stream and not use flash?

Comment: The reason I try to avoid hacking the stream is that it is against adobe policy to tamper with the rtmp protocol. This is a commercial app therefore I am trying to avoid any license issues. I have found a commercial solution at this site and I have implemented the driver sdk successfully in c++, for a fake webcam. Link is  http://www.e2esoft.cn/vcam/vcamsdk.asp